# Is it possible to leverage one template and one uploader/java scipt for multiple instances of uploader?

Tags: fine-uploader

This may be TOO much to ask, but I still want to ask as it looks like too much code on web pages.

I have following template and javascript for a single instance of uploader. In my case, I have to use 8 uploader instances in a page (ofcourse in tabs!). If at all possible, I DO NOT want to repeat below code chunks to all 8 uploaders. Is is possible to leverage code (template,javascript) for all uploaders.

Please see my javascript that I am trying to re-use; but on the execution it fails for ...Uncaught Error: Method ....*jsonStringCreatedByMyFunction - see my json string below*..... does not exist on jQuery.fineUploader

template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="qq-template-manual-trigger-section1">
    <div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader" qq-drop-area-text="Drop files here">
        <div class="qq-total-progress-bar-container-selector qq-total-progress-bar-container">
            <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-total-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar qq-total-progress-bar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="qq-upload-drop-area-selector qq-upload-drop-area" qq-hide-dropzone>
            <span class="qq-upload-drop-area-text-selector"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button">
                <div>Select files</div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" id="trigger-upload-section1" class="btn btn-primary">
                <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i> Upload
            </button>
        </div>
        <span class="qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing">
            <span>Processing dropped files...</span>
            <span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span>
        </span>
        <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals">
            <li>
                <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector">
                    <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar"></div>
                </div>
                <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
                <div>
                <img class="qq-thumbnail-selector" qq-max-size="80" qq-server-scale>                    
                <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
                <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
                <span class="qq-edit-filename-icon-selector qq-edit-filename-icon qq-editable" aria-label="Edit filename"></span>
                <input class="qq-edit-filename-selector qq-edit-filename" tabindex="0" type="text">
                </div>
                <span class="qq-upload-caption-selector qq-upload-caption"></span>
                <span class="qq-edit-caption-icon-selector qq-edit-caption-icon kk-editable" aria-label="Edit caption"></span>                    
                <input class="qq-edit-caption-selector qq-edit-caption kk-editing" placeholder="Caption  here ..." tabindex="0" type="text">
                <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-update-caption" onclick="captionUpdate(true);">Update Caption</button>

                <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-retry-selector qq-upload-retry">Retry</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete" onclick="captionUpdate(false);">Delete</button 

                <span role="status" class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>       
    </div>
</script>
```

Javascript:

```
    function getFineUploaderJsonObjectStr(sectionInd) {
    var requestObj =  new Object(); 
    requestObj.endpoint = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket';
    requestObj.accessKey = 'AKvcccccvccvBIA';

    var objectPropertiesObj =  new Object();
    objectPropertiesObj.key =   " function (fileId) { " +
                                "   return $('#login_name').val()+ '/' + $('#book_id).val() + '/' " + sectionInd + " '/' + $('#fine-uploader-manual-trigger-" + sectionInd + " ').fineUploader('getName',fileId); " +
                                " } ";

    var signatureObj =  new Object();
    signatureObj.endpoint = "http://localhost/app/ci/fine/endpoint";

    var uploadSuccessObj = new Object();
    uploadSuccessObj.endpoint = "http://localhost/app/ci/fine/endpoint?success";
    var uploadSuccessObjParams = new Object();
    uploadSuccessObjParams.isBrowserPreviewCapable = qq.supportedFeatures.imagePreviews;
    uploadSuccessObjParams.bookid = " function() { return $('#book_id').val(); } ";
    uploadSuccessObjParams.sectionid = " function() { return $('#section_id').val(); } ";
    uploadSuccessObjParams.section = " function() { return 'section1'; } ";
    uploadSuccessObj.params = uploadSuccessObjParams;

    var sessionObj = new Object();
    sessionObj.endpoint = "http://localhost/app/ci/fine/endpoint?filelist";
    var sessionObjParams = new Object();
    sessionObjParams.key =  " function() { " +
                            "   return $('#login_name').val()+ '/' + $('#book_id').val() + '/' " + sectionInd + " ; " +
                            " } ";
    sessionObj.params = sessionObjParams;

    var iframeSupportObj = new Object();
    iframeSupportObj.localBlankPagePath = "success.html";   

    var corsObj = new Object();
    corsObj.expected = true;

    var chunkingObj = new Object();
    chunkingObj.enabled = true;

    var resumeObj = new Object();
    resumeObj.enabled = true;

    var deleteFileObj = new Object();
    deleteFileObj.enabled = true;
    deleteFileObj.method = "POST";
    deleteFileObj.endpoint = "http://localhost/app/ci/fine/endpoint";
    var deleteFileParams = new Object();
    deleteFileParams.qqcaption = " function() { if (isCaptionUpdate === true) { return captionValue; } } ";
    deleteFileParams.bookid = " function() { return $('#book_id').val(); } ";
    deleteFileParams.sectionid = " function() { return $('#section1_id').val(); } ";
    deleteFileObj.params = deleteFileParams;    

    var validationObj = new Object();
    validationObj.itemLimit = 500;
    validationObj.sizeLimit = 15000000;

    var thumbnailsObj = new Object();
    var thumbnailsObjPlaceholders = new Object();
    thumbnailsObjPlaceholders.notAvailablePath = "http://localhost/app/ci/s3.fine-uploader/placeholders/not_available-generic.png";
    thumbnailsObjPlaceholders.waitingPath = "http://localhost/app/ci/s3.fine-uploader/placeholders/waiting-generic.png";
    thumbnailsObj.placeholders = thumbnailsObjPlaceholders; 

    var callbacksObj = new Object();
    callbacksObj.onComplete =   " function(id, name, response) { " +                    
                                "   if (response.success) { " +
                                "       setSectionImageCount('1', 'U', 0);  " +              
                                "   } " +
                                " } ";
    callbacksObj.onError =  " function(id, name, errorReason, xhrOrXdr) { " +
                            "   if (!isCaptionUpdate) {//isCaptionUpdate will return 206 " +
                            "       alert(qq.format('Error on file number {} - {}.  Reason: {}', id, name, errorReason)); " +
                            "   } " +
                            " } ";
    callbacksObj.onUpload = " function(id, fileName) {  " +
                            "   captionValue = qq(this.getItemByFileId(id)).getByClass('qq-edit-caption')[0].value; " +
                            "   this.setParams({'qqcaption':captionValue}); " +
                            " } ";
    callbacksObj.onDelete = " function(id) { " +
                            "   captionValue = qq(this.getItemByFileId(id)).getByClass('qq-edit-caption')[0].value; " +                             
                            "   //change sttaus to 'Updating..' if it is Caption update " +
                            "   var statusSpan = qq(this.getItemByFileId(id)).getByClass('qq-upload-status-text')[0]; " +
                            "   if (isCaptionUpdate === true) { " +
                            "       statusSpan.innerText = 'Updating...'; " +
                            "   }  " +          
                            " } ";
    callbacksObj.onDeleteComplete = " function(id, xhr, isError) { " +          
                                    "   if (!isError) { " +
                                    "       setSectionImageCount('1', 'D', 0); " +
                                    "   } else if (isCaptionUpdate === true) {  " +         
                                    "       statusSpan.innerText = ''; " +
                                    "   } " +
                                    " } ";
    callbacksObj.onSubmitted =  "  function (id, name) { " +        
                                " //nothing " +
                                "} ";
    callbacksObj.onStatusChange =   " function(id, oldStatus, newStatus) {  " +         
                                    "   if (oldStatus === 'submitting' && newStatus === 'submitted'){ " +
                                    "       //hide 'Update Caption' btn for uploading files " +
                                    "       var updateCaptionBtn = qq(this.getItemByFileId(id)).getByClass('qq-upload-update-caption')[0]; " +              
                                    "       qq(updateCaptionBtn).hide(); " +
                                    "   } " +
                                    " } ";
    callbacksObj.onSessionRequestComplete = " function(response, success, xhrOrXdr) { " +
                                            "   //alert(response.length); uploaded file count should be added to it; " +
                                            "   if (success) {              " +
                                            "       if (response.length > 0) { " +
                                            "           //$('#section1ImageCount').text(response.length); " +
                                            "           setSectionImageCount('1', 'I', response.length); " +            
                                            "       }  " +
                                            "       var uploader = this;         " +    
                                            "       response.forEach(function(item) {  " +
                                            "           var id = uploader.getUploads({uuid: item.uuid}).id; " +
                                            "           var fileEl = uploader.getItemByFileId(id); " +
                                            "           fileEl.querySelector('.qq-edit-caption').value = item.qqcaption; " +
                                            "       }) " +
                                            "   } " +
                                            " } ";

    var wrapperObj =  new Object();
    wrapperObj.template = 'qq-template-manual-trigger-'+sectionInd;
    //wrapperObj.template = 'qq-template-manual-trigger';
    wrapperObj.autoUpload = false;
    wrapperObj.debug = true;
    wrapperObj.request = requestObj;
    wrapperObj.objectProperties = objectPropertiesObj;
    wrapperObj.signature = signatureObj;
    wrapperObj.uploadSuccess = uploadSuccessObj;
    wrapperObj.session = sessionObj;
    wrapperObj.iframeSupport = iframeSupportObj;
    wrapperObj.cors = corsObj;
    wrapperObj.chunking = chunkingObj;
    wrapperObj.resume = resumeObj;
    wrapperObj.deleteFile = deleteFileObj;
    wrapperObj.validation = validationObj;
    wrapperObj.thumbnails = thumbnailsObj;
    wrapperObj.callbacks = callbacksObj;    
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(wrapperObj);
    console.log(jsonString);
    return jsonString;
};

var section1JsonStr = getFineUploaderJsonObjectStr('section1');
var section2JsonStr = getFineUploaderJsonObjectStr('section2');
$('#fine-uploader-manual-trigger-section1').fineUploaderS3(section1JsonStr);
$('#fine-uploader-manual-trigger-section2').fineUploaderS3(section2JsonStr);

$('#trigger-upload-section1').click(function() {
    $('#fine-uploader-manual-trigger-section1').fineUploaderS3('uploadStoredFiles');
});
$('#trigger-upload-section2').click(function() {
    $('#fine-uploader-manual-trigger-section2').fineUploaderS3('uploadStoredFiles');
});
```

jsonStringCreatedByMyFunction:

```
{"template":"qq-template-manual-trigger-section1","autoUpload":false,"debug":true,"request":{"endpoint":"http://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket","accessKey":"AKvvvvhjjjjAABIA"},"objectProperties":{"key":" function (fileId) { \treturn $('#login_name').val()+ '/' + $('#book_id).val() + '/' section1 '/' + $('#fine-uploader-manual-trigger-section1 ').fineUploader('getName',fileId);  } "},"signature":{"endpoint":"http://localhost/app/ci/fine/endpoint"},"uploadSuccess":{"endpoint":"http://localhost/app/ci/fine/endpoint?success","params":{"isBrowserPreviewCapable":true,"bookid":" function() { return $('#book_id').val(); } ","sectionid":" function() { return $('#section_id').val(); } ","section":" function() { return 'section1'; } "}},"session":{"endpoint":"http://localhost/app/ci/fine/endpoint?filelist","params":{"key":" function() { \treturn $('#login_name').val()+ '/' + $('#book_id').val() + '/' section1 ;  } "}},"iframeSupport":{"localBlankPagePath":"success.html"},"cors":{"expected":true},"chunking":{"enabled":true},"resume":{"enabled":true},"deleteFile":{"enabled":true,"method":"POST","endpoint":"http://localhost/app/ci/fine/endpoint","params":{"qqcaption":" function() { if (isCaptionUpdate === true) { return captionValue; } } ","bookid":" function() { return $('#book_id').val(); } ","sectionid":" function() { return $('#section1_id').val(); } "}},"validation":{"itemLimit":500,"sizeLimit":15000000},"thumbnails":{"placeholders":{"notAvailablePath":"http://localhost/app/ci/s3.fine-uploader/placeholders/not_available-generic.png","waitingPath":"http://localhost/app/ci/s3.fine-uploader/placeholders/waiting-generic.png"}},"callbacks":{"onComplete":" function(id, name, response) { \tif (response.success) { \t\tsetSectionImageCount('1', 'U', 0);  \t}  } ","onError":" function(id, name, errorReason, xhrOrXdr) { \tif (!isCaptionUpdate) {//isCaptionUpdate will return 206 \t\talert(qq.format('Error on file number {} - {}.  Reason: {}', id, name, errorReason)); \t}  } ","onUpload":" function(id, fileName) {  \tcaptionValue = qq(this.getItemByFileId(id)).getByClass('qq-edit-caption')[0].value; \tthis.setParams({'qqcaption':captionValue});  } ","onDelete":" function(id) { \tcaptionValue = qq(this.getItemByFileId(id)).getByClass('qq-edit-caption')[0].value; \t//change sttaus to 'Updating..' if it is Caption update \tvar statusSpan = qq(this.getItemByFileId(id)).getByClass('qq-upload-status-text')[0]; \tif (isCaptionUpdate === true) { \t\tstatusSpan.innerText = 'Updating...'; \t}   } ","onDeleteComplete":" function(id, xhr, isError) { \tif (!isError) { \t\tsetSectionImageCount('1', 'D', 0); \t} else if (isCaptionUpdate === true) {\t\t\tstatusSpan.innerText = ''; \t}  } ","onSubmitted":"  function (id, name) {  //nothing } ","onStatusChange":" function(id, oldStatus, newStatus) {  \tif (oldStatus === 'submitting' && newStatus === 'submitted'){ \t\t//hide 'Update Caption' btn for uploading files \t\tvar updateCaptionBtn = qq(this.getItemByFileId(id)).getByClass('qq-upload-update-caption')[0]; \t\tqq(updateCaptionBtn).hide(); \t}  } ","onSessionRequestComplete":" function(response, success, xhrOrXdr) { \t//alert(response.length); uploaded file count should be added to it; \tif (success) {        \t\t\t\tif (response.length > 0) { \t\t\t//$('#section1ImageCount').text(response.length); \t\t\tsetSectionImageCount('1', 'I', response.length); \t\t}  \t\tvar uploader = this;\t     \t\tresponse.forEach(function(item) {  \t\t\tvar id = uploader.getUploads({uuid: item.uuid}).id; \t\t\tvar fileEl = uploader.getItemByFileId(id); \t\t\tfileEl.querySelector('.qq-edit-caption').value = item.qqcaption; \t\t}) \t}  } "}}
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want to share the same instance of fine uploader in multiple "tabs" on a single page?

Comment: basically, user needs to upload files to specific S3 folders (prefixes). There are about 8 folders that user have to use. As you can see I have overridden key using 'objectProperties:'. so, currently I have planned to have 8 separate instances of uploaders (template, javascript), which I would like avoid as it is repeated code and bulky.

Comment: I have update main question with "my approach" - just a concept of course!  would it be suggested way for me....or any other way exists ??

Comment: let me do more experiment and get back!

Comment: Also, instead of just copying and pasting a lot of generic code, a better approach would be to include code that shows you have tried to solve the problem yourself. That code can then be used to ask one specific question.

Comment: updated with my re-usable javascript; I am trying to dynamically creation uploader option as jason string and pass that to fineUploaderS3(jasonString);  I am getting Uncaught Error: Method..jasonString...does not exist on jQuery.fineUploader

Comment: Think I resolved the specific error by change function to return Object rather than jsonString.

Comment: Great to hear! Please post the specifics of your solution as an answer.

Comment: I am stuck in the next step. objectPropertiesObj.key in the server comes up as javascript function body and not really a executed value of that function. Not sure what is my next step.

Comment: In the server I see  [key] =>  function() {  return $(\'#login_name\').val()+ \'/\' + $(\'#book_id\').val() + \'/\' section1 ;  }

Comment: Direction to the solution is here [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37943525/re-use-fine-uploader-code-for-multi-instance/37955686#37955686)