# Re-use fine uploader code for multi instance

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I am have multiple instances of fine uploader in a page. I do not want to repeat/duplicate fine uploader script and template for every uploader instance as it is lot of code in my case (6-8 uploader).

I have following:

```
$('#fine-uploader-manual-trigger-section1').fineUploaderS3({
    template: 'qq-template-manual-trigger-section1',
    autoUpload: false,
    debug: true,
    request: {
        endpoint: $("#s3_url").val(),
        accessKey: $("#access_key").val(),     
    },
});
$('#fine-uploader-manual-trigger-section2').fineUploaderS3({
    template: 'qq-template-manual-trigger-section2',
    autoUpload: false,
    debug: true,
    request: {
        endpoint: $("#s3_url").val(),
        accessKey: $("#access_key").val(),     
    },
});
.......
up to 6-8; as you can template code also repeat.
```

My goals is re-use script and possibly template using below approach. I need some advice or direction what might be solution. Certainly,I am trying avoid code duplication.

```
$('#fine-uploader-manual-trigger-section1').createUploader('section1');
$('#fine-uploader-manual-trigger-section2').createUploader('section2');

function createUploader(section) {
   return new fineUploaderS3({
    template: 'qq-template-manual-trigger'+section,
    autoUpload: false,
    debug: true,
    request: {
        endpoint: $("#s3_url").val(),
        accessKey: $("#access_key").val(),     
    },
  });
}
```

My question, how to instantiate `.fineUploaderS3` and attach that to `$('#fine-uploader-manual-trigger-section1')` ? Is above approach possible with the JQuery version?

Comment: First step is to stop using the jQuery plug-in wrapper. But most importantly, your question is not clear and I don't know what specifically you are trying to do.

Comment: hum...I was thinking that jQuery version is superior than regular. Not sure how big is the change for me!. Anyways to answer your question, I have 6-8 uploader in a page,each of them uploads to a specific sub-folders in S3. For the most part the only change in each uploader is specific sub-folder. Instead of duplicate uploader code and template for each instance,I want to be able to create 6-8 instances by calling one fine uploader script and template by passing sub-folder as parameter into it.

Comment: So you actually want 8 separate instances of fine uploader? Each attached to a different element?

Comment: Yes,each attached to separate DIV element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function that you can call to create a set of Fine Uploader S3 instances attached to unique elements w/ varying endpoints and templates:

```
function createUploader(uploaderInfo) {
   return new qq.s3.FineUploader({
      element: document.querySelector(uploaderInfo.elementSelector),
      template: document.querySelector(uploaderInfo.templateSelector),
      request: {
         endpoint: uploaderInfo.endpoint
      }
   })
}
```

...and you can call this function like this:

```
[
   {
      elementSelector: '#element1', 
      templateSelector: '#template1', 
      endpoint: 'endpoint/1'
   },
   {
      elementSelector: '#element2', 
      templateSelector: '#template2', 
      endpoint: 'endpoint/2'
   }
   ...
].forEach(function(uploaderInfo) {
   createUploader(uploaderInfo)
})
```

That's the general idea. You may, of course, modify the code to more closely suit your needs. If you need to track uploader instances, you can do that inside of the `forEach` loop too.

Comment: Awesome idea Ray and thanks so much!! I am going to experiment and update this thread.

Comment: I have implemented my solution based on Ray's direction and it went very smooth. Of course,I had to make lot of specific customization,hence adding code here may not be useful. Thanks again to Ray for his great support with concrete examples.